# No route matches show action error thrown after submitting form with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a `select_tag` in a form within my Rails 3 app. When I select a vacation, and the form is submitted, I'd like to be routed to the `show` action on my `vacations_controller`. Here is the code for my form:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "vacations", :action => "show"), :method => 'get', :id => "song_selector" do %>
  <%= select_tag "vacation_id", options_for_select([["Choose your vacation", ""]]+ Vacation.active.collect {|vacation| [ vacation.title, vacation.id ] } ) %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I try that, I get an error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"vacations", :action=>"show"}
```

I definitely have a route for this:

```
resources :vacations, :only => [:index, :show]
```

And the output of rake routes:

```
vacation       GET       /vacations/:id(.:format)       vacations#show
```

I know from previous answers that I'm just not passing the ID in the URL as expected. If I raise params it looks like my ID is being passed as a string like so: `"vacations" => "2".

So I'm wondering: How I can construct my select_tag so this is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the id in that action.

Try:

```
<%= select_tag "id", options_for_select([["Choose your vacation", ""]]+ Vacation.active.collect {|vacation| [ vacation.title, vacation.id ] } ) %>
```

But this will not be ideal either, as the url will likely be something like "/vacations/?id=X".

An alternative is to use javascript and build the url based on the select option, that way you can construct the url the way you like it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm currently building the url with javascript but was wondering if I could use Rails to fix it instead.

Comment: The problem is that by submitting it via form you're not using Rails's url facilities, so the id will be appended as a normal parameter. This will still work but it's not ideal.